# Cu/Zn in salt water voltaic cell peculiar behavior -- any explanation?

Tags: home-experiment, electrochemistry

I was playing with my eight-year old son and his new 'lemon battery' kit -- it has 4 Copper plates, 4 zinc plates, a red LED, and pieces of wire hooked together.

Having no lemons handy, I decided to use salt water (regular Iodized kitchen salt dissolved in tap water). Being lazy too, I decided 3 cells in series would be good enough for the LED to glow (I guess the $V_L$ of the red LED is ~2V ... and each Cu/Zn cell makes maybe ~1V each?) ... and sure enough, it is: the LED lights up, and my kids are suitably impressed.

Now the funny part -- since I made 3 cells, I still had one spare Cu plate and one spare Zn plate.

1. When I take the **spare Zn plate**, and **touch the submerged part** of the **Cu (+) electrode** of **any of the three cells** with it, the **LED stops glowing**.
2. When I take the Zn plate away -- the LED starts glowing again.

So my question is, **why is this happening**? I could not answer my son when he asked: that was embarrassing! The LED **does not** stop glowing when I touch:

1. A (spare) Cu plate to any submerged Zn (-) electrode
2. A (spare, dry) Zn plate to the **non-submerged** part of the Cu electrode
3. A (spare) Zn plate to any submerged Zn electrode
4. A (spare) Cu plate to any submerged Cu electrode

Another observation is, when I take the Zn plate away from the submerged Cu electrode, the LED lights up but doesn't reach full brightness instantly -- the brightness increases from zero to full over a period of about one second.

Any guidance? Thanks...

Comment: Very nice experiment and description thereof! Notice BTW that a lemon is primarily acid, so the current carriers are $H^+$ (if I recall my chemistry correctly) while in salt water you've got ionized sodium and chlorine atoms.  I'm guessing that Zn is more reactive in salt water than Cu and that leads to your point 1 of non-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submerge either the zinc plate or the copper plate and touch the two together you are creating another (local) cell within your cell which is analogous to connecting a battery in parallel to one of three batteries connected in series (see illustration below). But when you do this you need to take care in how you connect that parallel battery.

[image]

If the the parallel (local) cell polarity is in the same direction as the main cell (A.) - then no problem you have the same voltage you started with. But if you connect the cell in the opposite direction (B.) you create a short circuit between the local and main cell. All the current flows in this short, and the current in the three cells in series goes to zero.

[image]

Connecting the extra copper to the zinc plate is like having a battery in parallel with the same polarity. And when the zinc plate is connected to a copper - opposite polarity. In your experiment, as in the case of connecting a battery in parallel, but 'backwards', when you connect copper to zinc nearly all the current you generate for that cell all circulates through the local cell - and the LED gets very little if any at all.

And the reason the LED takes time to illuminate is that unlike electrons in the metals, the ions that flow in the electrolyte don't (almost) immediately flow. It takes considerably more time for the ionic bridge to form.

Comment: Hi, may I request out to explain in a bit more detail how touching an electrode with the spare plate is analogous to connecting a battery in parallel? Didn't quite understand that ... especially since I am holding the other end of the spare plate between my fingers -- which are completely dry (even once held the plate with some tissue paper to keep it insulated from my skin). I'm sure you are right (and I seem to remember that if I did the reverse -- touch a Zn electrode with a Cu plate -- the LED got a tiny bit brighter if anything) -- its only that I can't quite grasp the equivalence. Thanks

Comment: @Avijit Please excuse my poor artsmanship, but I hope the drawings I've added help better illustrate what's going on. To convince yourself, and to help your son visualize what's going on you can try the same experiment using batteries as I've drawn - but be careful! The shorted batteries will heat very quickly! Always wear eye protection.

Comment: Actually your artsmanship is great! But what happens when I touch a *Zn* electrode with a *Cu* plate? (In your second picture, if the central plate is now copper and it is in contact with the Zn electrode *below* it?) Why isn't there a loop then also? I guess what I'm asking is, why isn't there a symmetry between the two cases? DoI need to know a bit more detail about how a voltaic cell actually works at the electrochemical level? Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, for a more complete illustration I probably should have included both situations - copper touching zinc as well as zinc touching copper - to match the battery drawings. Note that when the batteries are all in the same direction the LED is lit and current is flowing in a clockwise direction as seen from above. But when a battery is placed backwards in parallel with another, current flows in a counterclockwise direction - opposite to the main clockwise flow of current...

Comment: In the 2nd illustration I've shown the copper is connected to the zinc and the local current flows in a counterclockwise direction - opposite to how the direction current needs to flow from the local cell into the other cells. But rather if a copper plate were connected to the zinc plate in that cell ( not illustrated) the current of that local connection would be clockwise, adding to the current traveling through all the cells. I hope that helps now..